# Accessing Firestore locally with gcloud, only personal account works?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

To simplify the problem, I created a simple Google Cloud project in my company Google Cloud organization. I activated Firestore API and created a Native (default) Firestore database. I ran gcloud init and specified the project and one of the company Google account as the authenticated user. This user has the "owner" IAM role. I then copy/pasted a [simple nodejs code example from Google's nodejs-firestore-session](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore-session) to test Firestore as an express session store. Then get this error when I host the nodejs locally:

> Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

As I said before, the company Google account has "owner" role in the IAM Google Cloud project. I can list the Firestore databases using gcloud for example. I then added my personal Gmail account has a IAM "owner" role in the company project.

And now, the sample nodejs code works **even if I am still logged in with my company Google account with gcloud**. I can see the documents created in the sessions collection in the Firestore database. It only works when I add my personal Gmail account, when I remove the owner role of my personal Gmail account, I get the permission denied error again.

I think this means the access to Firestore is not using my gcloud credentials but something else... I tried to search online for answers but it is hard to find because almost everything regarding Firestore is related to Firebase which I don't use for the session store.

Do you have any hints on what I should look for to be able to access Firestore using the company Google account only?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! Just found out what was going on. I thought I was logged on both accounts in gcloud when I was switching gcloud configuration with gcloud init but I was still logged in with my personnal account the whole time. I just had to run gcloud auth login and use the company Google account.